# How to exclude a certain selection from a collection_select list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Simply I have a `collection_select` which allows a user to select any users that share the same `business.id`. It uses the list `@colleagues` created in Ruby:

```
#events_controller#new
@colleagues = User.where(business_id: current_user.business_id)


#events/new.html.erb
<%= f.collection_select :id,
                        @colleagues,
                        :id,
                        :full_name %>
```

But at the moment, this list **includes** the `current_user`, which I do not want to happen (the user should *not* be able to select them self). **Is there a way I can exclude the `current_user` from this list from querying the database?** I am using SQLite.

Thank you, and any further explanation would be much appreciated as I am new to Ruby and SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might pass to collection_select something like

```
@colleagues.reject {|user| user.id == current_user.id }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@colleagues = User.where(business_id: current_user.business_id).where.not(id: current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me in rails 6.0.0

```
form.collection_select :parent_id, Collection.all.where.not(id: collection.id), :id, :title
```